# Link to "view reputation changes" from user page (under user image) has incorrect underline position

Tags: bug, status-completed

Simple bug: You go to your user profile, under the image there is your reputation which links to reputation changes (something like this:

```
http://askubuntu.com/users/*****/*******?tab=reputation
```

However, when you hover over that number (your reputation, under your image, in your profile), it is supposed to be underlined (as I can see in stackOverflow for example), but the line appears 1/3 way from the bottom over the number, kind of crossing the number out. A bit similar to <del>this</del>. Here is a snapshot of how it looks like:

[image]

I am using Firefox 7.0.1 for Ubuntu. I'm using Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: What browser and version of that browser are you using and can you by any change upload a screenshot of that?

Comment: @OctavianDamiean, yeah right! It sounded so simple I forgot to mention those. I will edit my post now. Just in case, is there a command (I'm using firefox) that would dump all the information all at once that I can use? Something with output like: Firefox version bla addons this and that plugins blabla

Comment: You are right. I can reproduce this bug on a clean install of Firefox 7.0.1 on 11.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is a CSS rule of the class `.summarycount`.

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

This is causing the underline to appear way higher up than it should.

Comment: I don't know if this is the real answer, but I'm gonna accept anyway. At this moment though, I can't see the list of changes to my reputation, so that reputation number is not a link anymore. Neither is the one on the top bar, next to my name!